# Accidentally changed default open program in windows - how can I change back?

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtualbox, windows-explorer

I'm on Windows 10, and I was tinkering around trying to open a VirtualBox VM that I transferred from another machine. When I saw that the VMs I transferred weren't showing in the GUI, I decided to try to open one of their `.vdi` files directly, and I accidentally set it to open by default with VirtualBox - the image has changed permanently.. How can I change the default program back? I guess it isn't so important but it's bothering me because it is wrong. I tried uninstalling & reinstalling vbox but it remains!

Here's an image - the left is correct, the right is what I've done.

[image]

Comment: Start, Settings, Apps, Default Apps, scroll down the right, Choose Apps by File Type.   See if you can remove the association there.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise that was an option. I couldn't see any way other than resetting all defaults, but this solved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When App associations get changed or screwed up, the Windows 10 Association settings to fix the association.

Start, Settings, Apps, Default Apps, and scroll down the right side to find the app and remove the association there.

See screen shot.

[image: Change Associations]